# No funciona el emulador de android

Tags: android, android-studio

Cuando intento ejecutar el emulador en "tool window" me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ahi modifique la pregunta, perdon pense que me habia logueado al foro en ingles jajajaja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el emulador de Android no se inicia correctamente, este problema suele deberse a problemas con HAXM. Los problemas de HAXM suelen ser el resultado de conflictos con otras tecnologías de virtualización, configuraciones incorrectas o un controlador HAXM desactualizado. Intente reinstalar el controlador HAXM, siguiendo los pasos en Instalación de HAXM.

Comment: Es SO en Español.

Comment: Perdon por la pregunta en ingles hubo un mal entendido por parte mia, ahi lo modifique. El problema que tenia realmente fue que al ejecutarlo en "tool window" que es algo de la nueva actualizacion de android no se porque motivo pero no me funcionaba. Asi que lo tuve que ejecutar como antes, es decir, con el emulador aparte

Comment: Ya traduje la respuesta